# C# - printing 1 column in a matrix with updated data

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# in highschool at the moment. I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to do the following:

I have a task where I need to print a matrix, update it using cases and later on print one of the columns with the updated data.
First, I created a simple matrix that prints -1 on a 20 on 5 square:

```
bankMatrix = new int[20, 5];
for (int i = 0; i < bankMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bankMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,3}", bankMatrix[i, j] = -1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Which outputs the following:

```
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Next, the user chooses a column from 1-5 via a case statement and the matrix gets updated:

```
Console.WriteLine("please choose where would you like to create your account (we have 5 branches, choose one):");
                    int accountBranch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (accountBranch > 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("we only have 5 branches. please choose from them");
                        break;
                    }
                    accountBranch = accountBranch - 1;
                    bool branch = false;
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < bankMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        if (bankMatrix[i, accountBranch] == -1)
                        {
                            branch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("sorry but this branch is full. please choose another 
                            branch.");
                            break;
                        }
                        if (branch)
                    {
                        bankMatrix[i, accountBranch] = 0;
                        Console.WriteLine("account saved on branch {0}, vault {1}", accountBranch + 1, i);
                    }
```

Here is the code for the updated matrix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bankMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bankMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,3}", bankMatrix[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
```

now comes the part I'm struggling at. I need to print the column the user chooses with the updated data so for exemple, if the user chose to print column 4, and there is only one 0 at the top of the column, it should output this:

```
 0
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

I tried to do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("what branch?");
                        int branchShowBalance = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        branchShowBalance = branchShowBalance - 1;
                        int[,] balanceMatrix;
                        balanceMatrix = new int[20, 1];
                        for (int K = 0; K < balanceMatrix.GetLength(0); K++)
                        {
                            for (int H = 0; H < balanceMatrix.GetLength(1); H++)
                            {
                                Console.Write("{0,3}", balanceMatrix[K, H]);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
```

but it only outputs the column with a lot of 0, and not the updated data:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: A suggestion, to make it easier to debug, consider initializing your matrix with 10 time the row number plus the column number.  That way, when you see some data, you can easily understand if it's in the right place.  If you need everything to be -1, then change it to -1 after you finish.  I haven't gone through your code, but you need to make sure you get your column numbers (which are numbered internally 0-4) handled properly, since your UI treats them as 1-5

Comment: This is a great time to learn the other side of the programming coin - debugging. This is important to know because _nobody_ writes perfect code on their first attempt, regardless of how experienced or brilliant they are. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your program. Observe how each statement affects the variables. Did the statement that was just executed do what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are again very close to the solution. The reason for the zeros is that you just create your new array but do not fill values from your old array. The default value for an integer is 0 in C#. So when you print your new matrix you just get zeros. Here is a solution for your problem:

```
        // Get column value
        Console.WriteLine("what branch?");
        int columnIndex = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        columnIndex = columnIndex - 1;

        // Create new column matrix
        int[,] balanceMatrix = new int[20, 1];

        // Set new matrix values from the bankMatrix
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < balanceMatrix.GetLength(0); rowIndex++)
        {
            balanceMatrix[rowIndex, 0] = bankMatrix[rowIndex, columnIndex];
        }

        // Print values
        for (int K = 0; K < balanceMatrix.GetLength(0); K++)
        {
            for (int H = 0; H < balanceMatrix.GetLength(1); H++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,3}", balanceMatrix[K, H]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Oh I see what I missed. Thank you!